# LINQ Statement for Generic List

Tags: linq

I have a bool array and a List:

```
bool[ ] searchable

List<T> allData
```

What I want to do is like the following

```
allData.Where(c => searchable[0] && c[0].Contains("das") ||
                   searchable[1] && c[1].Contains("das") ||
                   searchable[2] && c[2].Contains("das")
                   ...
              );
```

How can I construct this LINQ function?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is `T`? Is it `string`?

Answer (score 5):

Use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx) of `Where` that provides your filtering callback with the index of the element being considered along with the element itself:

```
var results = allData.Where((c, i) => searchable[i] && c.Contains("das"));
```

Comment: @user944592: You will need to write a method on whatever `c` is that does so. You could also use reflection to do it dynamically, but that will be 100x slower.